# Excel multi layer if vlookup and formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, if

I've produced a simplified document that shows the essence of what I'm trying to achieve.

The image of the document:
[image: Picture]

There are 5 shops that all stock Apples, Pears, Bananas, and Oranges.

Internally stock is moved and bought very regularly. Hence the 'Stock Location and Amount' Section. Below is the 'September Stock Movement' - which shows where the stock has moved to and from. There is also an option if more stock is bought or sold - from the bank.

I need to create a formula that tracks the internal stock depending on the 'September Stock Movement' section - I've filled in some details to this section. If the formula in the 'Stock Location and Amount' section was complete then the data below would apply/work.

If it's a transfer of stock then it needs to reduce one shop's stock and add to the other. If it's a buy then it just needs to add it directly to the location of the shop receiving the purchase and reduce the balance in the bank, and if it's a sell it needs to reduce the shops stock but increase the bank's balance.

Note - the prices of the products are different.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: =IF(AND(B2=H2,$C$1=K2),VLOOKUP(B2,$H$2:$K$5,2,FALSE),"")

Comment: Initially, I was trying to figure out how I can input the data depending on the place it was location it was going to. Then once i'd figured that out I would focus on the buy/sell/transfer. 

Yet to have figured out the first part yet haha. If you could provide some insight that'd be great. The formula above references the actual sheet and not the image - it's why the locations may be different.

Comment: For your data format you'll need `sumifs`. Really you'll need 2, one to get all the adds to a  particular shop and the second is the subtractions. kind of like `=sumifs(add) - sumifs(subtractions)`

Comment: another is just reforming the movement section to show all shops and bank (like your stock location section), then it's just a matter of summing the columns.

Comment: SUMIF function?

Comment: Thanks all - think I've got there now. Just some refinements. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but is a nightmare to do without a helper column.  What you want is another column in your stock movement section that has the value.  It should have a formula with something like (this would go in G15):

= **[amount cell relative reference (eg D15)]** * INDEX( **[values range (eg. $B$25:$B$28)]**, MATCH(**[item cell relative reference (eg C15)]**, **[Value of Item range (eg. $A$25:$A$28)]**, 0) )

You then have a formula under Shop1 Apples (cell C3 in your example), that is something like

= SUMIFS( **[value cell range (eg $G$15:$G$20)]**, **[Venue (To) cell range (eg $F$15:$F$20)]**, **[Shop header cell (eg C$2)]**, **[Item range (eg $C$15:$C$20)]**, **[Row TOKEN (eg $A3)]** ) - SUMIFS( **[value cell range (eg $G$15:$G$20)]**, **[Venue (From) cell range (eg $E$15:$E$20)]**, **[Shop header cell (eg C$2)]**, **[Item range (eg $C$15:$C$20)]**, **[Row TOKEN (eg $A3)]** )

If you need to do it without creating a helper column then I believe you will have to break out array formulas, which is not something I can just type up an easy answer for.

Answer (score 0):

I had some help from someone in an excel forum and they came back with:

In C6 - drag across and down
=SUM(SUMIFS($D$18:$D$23,$C$18:$C$23,$A6,$F$18:$F$23,C$5,$B$18:$B$23,{"Transfer","Buy"}))-SUM(SUMIFS($D$18:$D$23,$C$18:$C$23,$A6,$E$18:$E$23,C$5,$B$18:$B$23,{"Transfer","Buy"}))

in C10 (corrected)

=SUMIFS($D$18:$D$23,$B$18:$B$23,"Sell",$E$18:$E$23,C$5)-SUMIFS($D$18:$D$23,$B$18:$B$23,"Buy",$F$18:$F$23,C$5)

Copy across

in H6

=SUMIFS($D$18:$D$23,$B$18:$B$23,"Sell",$C$18:$C$23,$A6)-SUMIFS($D$18:$D$23,$B$18:$B$23,"Buy",$C$18:$C$23,$A6)

copy down

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).